# Corey-Seebach reaction regioselectivity

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Does [Corey-Seebach reaction](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/corey-seebach-reaction.shtm) with conjugated enones undergo in a direct or conjugated fashion?
[image]

Can the two sulfur atoms soften the carbanion enough for it to undergo conjugated addition? If not, would addition of Cu(I) enhance the proportion of conjugated addition?

Comment: Are you talking about forming the dithiane? or the addition of a lithiated dithiane *into* a conjugated enone? (I'm guessing the former, but the Corey-Seebach reaction is usually described as the addition of the dithiane rather than its formation)

Comment: No, I've meant the latter. I bet on direct addition.

Comment: If I remember correctly, 2-phenyl-2-lithio-1,3-dithiane exclusively yields the thermodynamically controlled 1,4-addition product when reacted with cyclohexen-2-one in THF at room temperature. At -78 °C under otherwise similar conditions, the  the kinetic 1,2-addition product is predominantly (~ 2:1) obtained. Adding HMPA to the lithiated dithiane prior to adding the enone also favoured reaction in Michael fashion, even at low temperatures.

Comment: Okay, is't all about conditions. I could accept your comment as an answer if you provide a reference.